# Resolve relative import in own module

Tags: python, python-import

```
helloPython
  __init__.py
  
  myutil
    __init__.py
    mymaths.py

  service
    __init__.py
    cal.py
```

mymaths.py

```
def myadd(a, b):
    return a+b
```

cal.py

```
from ..myutil import mymaths #or any other similar import statement

sum = mymaths.myadd(3, 4)
```

Here, in cal.py, I want to use a method defined in mymaths.py as above
However when I try to import, I get below error, when I "Run Python file in terminal" in VSCode Tried multiple ways

1. First method

   from ..myutil import mymaths

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

2. Second method

   from helloPython.myutil import mymaths

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloPython'

Comment: Might be helpful: [Relative imports in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-in-python-2-7)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to understand what is script and module. Seems the concept is not that simple to grasp. In java, I can just do import com.package.class from any class from any packages/subpackage and the main() function gets executed. Coming from the java background, I still cannot convince myself that I understood python imports and relative import or anything related to import.

This should be the most basic concept for any programming language and I see like hundreds and thousands of questions on python only on **import**

Comment: VSCode is likely complicating the situation, since how it executes the code may be affecting your results.

Comment: @napuzba Thanks a lot, I got your article link from somewhere. Read and tried it. It's very well explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Relative imports in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-in-python-2-7) and [ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent) helped me to understand. Thanks to [@napuzba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6582873/napuzba)
and [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau)